# Getting Java error cannot resolve to variable

Tags: java, sql, variables

I've searched on this and I still can't seem to find the right answer.  I'm trying to pull data back from a database and add a bunch of objects to an ArrayList.  My IDE is telling me that the objMessage in the messages.add(objMessage) line cannot be resolved to a variable.  Why is it telling me this when I declared ArrayList messages = null at the beginning of my function?

Thanks!

```
    ArrayList<Message> messages = null;

    try {
        sqlConn = ds.getConnection();           
        sqlConnector = new SQLConnector(sqlConn);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE thing = 1;";

        rs = sqlConnector.getData(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            String stuff = rs.getString("stuff");

            if(stuff.toUpperCase().contains(stuff.toUpperCase())) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String data = rs.getString("data");
                Date time = rs.getDate("time");
                Message objMessage = new Message(id, time, data);
            }

            messages.add(objMessage);   
        }
      catch(Exception e) {
     // catch exception
      }
```

Comment: you are initializing `messages` to `null`... at the very least, the instantiation should be: `ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `objMessage` is declared inside the braces of your `if` block. It doesn't exist outside of that block. Presumably moving your line `messages.add(objMessage)` up into the `if` block will get rid of that particular error.

But then your `messages` object is null, so you're still not going to be able to add anything to it.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I didn't understand why it kept saying null pointer if i put it in the if statement, but then it generated this error when I moved it outside of the if statement.  Forgot I declared the variable and set it to null and didn't instantiate a new object.  Stupid mistake.  Thank you!